# vuestrap spinner unable to listen to shown event

Tags: vue.js

https://github.com/yuche/vue-strap/blob/master/src/Spinner.vue
https://github.com/yuche/vue-strap/blob/master/docs/example/spinnerDocs.vue

Looking at the reference implementation, I've tried to do the same here: https://jsfiddle.net/gw3br69r/2/

I've tried listening to different events like `show`, `show:spinner`, `spinner`, `spinner:shown`, etc, and have also tried to listen to the event via `$on` detailed here: https://vuejs.org/api/#vm-on and https://vuejs.org/guide/components.html#Parent-Child-Communication but I'm unable to listen to that event. I have also tried the non minified debug build of vue.js, but I do not know of a way to track down all the events to see if `shown:spinner` is even getting called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code would work if the Spinner component used `$dispatch()` to "propagate upward along the parent chain".

But looking [at the source code](https://github.com/yuche/vue-strap/blob/master/src/Spinner.vue#L69), we see that `$broadcast()` is used, to "propagate downward to all descendants".

I don't know why they are broadcasting instead of dispatching, and I don't understand how their documentation example works. It seems impossible. Something must have been tweaked or changed.

Anyway, an event broadcasted by a "child" can be listened by its "parent" by using `v-on`. It goes like this:

```
<spinner v-on:shown::spinner="doSomething"></spinner>
```

See the working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/x80ph0mk/1/